# How can I create a new img tag and fill it with JavaScript picture?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I'm trying to develop an app (using Cordova) where I need to get an flexible number of pictures and add them in a div tag.

Let's say this is my  in HTML where I call the JavaScript function and where I want to have all the pictures taken by that button:

```
<div id="DynamicGallery">
            <button id= "DynamicPicture" onclick="openCamera();">Take Picture Dynamically</button>
            <div id="DynamicPictureTaken">

            </div>
        </div>
```

And this is my JavaScript which get the pictures:

```
function openCamera(selection) {

// start image capture
navigator.device.capture.captureImage(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit:10});

// capture callback
var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {
    var i, path, len;
    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
        // do something interesting with the file
    }
};

// capture error callback
var captureError = function(error) {
    navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
};
```

}

How can I get the X pictures displayed in div tag?
Is it possible to create dinamically the img tag with the picture inside?

Thank you all guys

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You want `document.createElement`. first, you snag the div you want to add them to using `pictures = document.getElementById("DynamicPictureTaken");`, then append them using:

```
var img = document.createElement("img")
img.setAttribute("src", path);
pictures.appendChild(img);
```

I'm not 100% familiar with `device.capture.captureImage` but if i'm understanding correctly, that should do the job.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, even if it's not working, yet. I'm using device.capture.captureImage because navigator.camera.getPicture doesn't allow me to get more than one picture.

Here there's the edited code with your suggestion: http://pastebin.com/KiCxEVBE

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the following code after some edits:

```
function openCamera() {

var options = {
    //limit: 2
    quality: 50,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: true
};

navigator.device.capture.captureImage(onSuccess, onError, options);
pictures = document.getElementById("DynamicPictureTaken");

function onSuccess(mediaFiles) {
    var i, path, len;

    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
        //console.log(mediaFiles);
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(mediaFiles));

        var img = document.createElement("img"); //$('<img id="dynamic">');
        img.setAttribute("src", path);
        img.setAttribute('width', '20%');
        img.setAttribute('height', '20%');
        img.setAttribute('id', 'DeficiencyDynamicImage');
        pictures.appendChild(img);
    }
}

function onError(error) {
    navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
}
```

}